# Thin laptops overheating

Tags: overheating

I got a notebook that is thing less than an inch, but it overheats sometimes. Is anyone of you also having a thin laptop and is it overheating? My cpu cores are usualt 45-55C and in playing games up to 65-70. Is that okay? ( The laptop gets really warm while playing games )

Comment: The thinner a laptop, the more prone for it to overheat since there's less space for airflow. However you have to specify the make and model, specs and all. What GPU, CPU do you have? etc. because CPU cores usually being at 45-50C seems unlikely even for an ultrathin laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specs of your laptop, you don't really have to worry about them overheating at the temperatures you are seeing (65-70) under load. The fairly new generations of laptops's hardware can handle this heal without problem.

Additionally, the reason you are seeing this temperature is because laptops usually only have 1 or 2 fans to cool them down. Since the laptops, or ultrabooks are so thin, they more heavily rely on heat-sinks in order to cool them down. These small heat-sinks allow the manufacturer to shrink the size of the laptop and allow for a lighter design.

You really have nothing to worry about with that temperature. However, if you want to help the laptop cool, you can look into a laptop cooling pad.

Comment: I agree your answer, but what about the high temperature for the battery and cpu life? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: The heat will not effect the CPU life at those temperatures. Unless your CPU is at 90+ degrees C for long, extended periods of time, you have nothing to worry about. Ultrabooks or "thin-laptops" are built with the heat dissapation in-mind, and the CPU will not deteriorate over time - In terms of the battery, this should also not be a problem. The computers battery life will probably start reducing from normal wear-and-tear rather than the temperature. - However, if your battery can be removed, you can do so when gaming for long periods of time